# How to get followers and following list in Instagram via http requests

Tags: python, instagram

I'm looking for a possibility to get a followers and following list in JSON format via web request (in the same way as on the Instagram web site).
For example, I can login via requests, and get user info:

```
def get_user_info(self, user_name):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + user_name + "/?__a=1"
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print 'Seems like dns lookup failed..'
        time.sleep(60)
        return None
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print 'User: ' + user_name + ' status code: ' + str(r.status_code)
        print r
        return None
    info = json.loads(r.text)
    return info['user']
```

I tried to see what request chrome send to server, but was unsuccessful. 
The question is: how to prepare a similar get or post request to retrieve followers list without the Instagram API?

Comment: page not found.

Answer (score 14):

GraphQL queries with `query_hash` = "58712303d941c6855d4e888c5f0cd22f" (followings) and "37479f2b8209594dde7facb0d904896a" (followers) return this information. With being logged in, do a GET query to instagram.com/graphql/query with parameters `query_hash` and `variables`, where `variables` is a JSON-formatted set of variables `id` (user id, as in the return dictionary of your `get_user_info()` function), `first` (a page length, it seems the current maximum is 50) and in subsequent requests `after` set to the `end_cursor` in the previous response dictionary.

Alternatively, the [Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/) library provides a convenient way to login and then programmatically access a profile's followers and followings list.

```
import instaloader

# Get instance
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
L.login(USER, PASSWORD)        # (login)
L.interactive_login(USER)      # (ask password on terminal)
L.load_session_from_file(USER) # (load session created w/
                               #  `instaloader -l USERNAME`)

# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)

# Print list of followees
for followee in profile.get_followees():
    print(followee.username)

# (likewise with profile.get_followers())
```

Besides `username`, the attributes `full_name`, `userid`, `followed_by_viewer` and many more are defined in the `Profile` instance that is returned for each followee.

Comment: Seems like a lot of similar tool is using `GraphQL` with `query_hash` for followers. I am trying to approach the same thing use Java. Do you think it is applicable? Do you have any code to share? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aandergr is that ok that every 1k scraped followers i get blocked to ~10 minutes cuz of: `Too many queries in the last time. Need to wait 630 seconds, until ...` Can I somehow pass through that?

Answer (score -4):

Easy(just replace _a with __a)

```
'https://www.instagram.com/'+user_name+'/followers/?_a=1'
'https://www.instagram.com/'+user_name+'/following/?_a=1'
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but it redirect on user_name main page, but how to get followers list?

Comment: I tried on public account. Does it work in your case?

Comment: Yeah, it's work in browser, with requests.get or with curl

Comment: Could you attach screenshot from browser here for any public account?

Comment: Disabled for sure. Will prompt login.