# How to scroll down dialog box on Instagram with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I have a list of users, for which I want to extract their followers on Instagram. I am trying to scroll through the follower dialog box and append every follower to a list, so I end up with the full list of followers of a user before I move on to do the same for the next user.

This is my code:

```
for username in username_column:
    currentRow=currentRow+1
    userprofile = browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + username)

    # Find the "followers" link, click it and wait 2 seconds
    followersLink = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul/li[2]/a")
    followersLink.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    # Find the dialog box 
    followersList = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[role=\'dialog\'] ul")
    numberOfFollowersInList = len(followersList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li'))
    followersList.click()
    actionChain = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
    followers = []

    # As long as the number of followers in the list is lower than number required
    # press SPACE. After each press, we refresh the number of users we have in the list
    # and print it.

    while (numberOfFollowersInList < max):

        actionChain.key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        numberOfFollowersInList = len(followersList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li'))
        followersInList = followersList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li')
        for element in followersInList:
            followerData = element.text
            print(followerData)
            followers.append(followerData)
            #print(followers)
        followersList.click()
```

However, this returns me a lot of duplicate follower data and when I watch the browser (driver) do it on Instagram, it is like it gets stuck, while scrolling and doesn't know where to start scrolling from once it's scrolled once. I hope it's clear what I wrote.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This might be helpful https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy

Comment: To achieve the same goal without selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658723/how-to-get-followers-and-following-list-in-instagram-via-http-requests