# How to scrape similar/related accounts from instagram in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to scrape accounts which are similar/related to a given account in instagram. Querying URLS: [https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?_a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?_a=1) doesn't provide this information.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all followers and followings of a user, what I guess based of your question. [aandergr made answered that in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658723/how-to-get-followers-and-following-list-in-instagram-via-http-requests)
If not let me know how you define "similar"

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am looking for suggested accounts. For example - If i follow maccosmetics then other beauty brands would be similar/suggested accounts to follow.

Comment: Ah ok, can't seem to find something for that. good luck

Answer (score 0):

A way to get this is from link: [https://www.instagram.com/{username}](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D) and info comes as "edge_related_profiles":{"edges":[{"node":{".....}}]}

And to get this, we need to be authenticated to the site as a guest and should NOT be logged in. I am still investigating the reason of this but yes workaround is possible.

Update 04/18/2022 =>
This queryhash works fine to pull suggested/similar accounts:
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=7c16654f22c819fb63d1183034a5162f

Comment: Any update regarding this? It seems to work okay when not logged in but that leads to instagram redirect towards login page.

Comment: @Waqar Please try with query in the updated  answer.