# Using requests to check instagram pages followers follower count

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, instaloader

The title sounds a bit confusing but I am trying to get the follower count of all of the followers of an instagram page. So an example output would be

```
John  17  followers 
adam  120 followers
will  172 followers
```

This is what I have so far but after this point I am not sure how to pull that data with what requests is giving me. This is because I am not seeing the actual follower data coming in. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests
username = "nfl"
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + username
r = requests.get(url).text
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to use requests module to scrape content from html website. You can use beautifulsoup or scrapy module to scrape content from websites.

You can also [Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/) library provides a convenient way to login and then programmatically access a profile's followers and followings list.

Ref: [Use instaloader to get followers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315443/13779320)